# "ValueError: Cannot convert notebook to v5 because that version doesn't exist" (when trying to import notebook as module)

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-import

Hey dear stackoverflowers,

I always get "ValueError: Cannot convert notebook to v5 because that version doesn't exist",
when trying to import another jupyter notebook as module, 
do you have any suggestions how i could solve this issue?

I already tried it with the official Juypter solution for importing notebooks as modules, but it gives me the same results as when i tried it by importing "import_ipynib", "ipynb", or "nbimporter".

It always throws 
"ValueError: Cannot convert notebook to v5 because that version doesn't exist".

The code i tried:

```
import ipynb, import_ipynb, nbimporter # I pip installed those before
import _01_AutoCollect_DataSet
```

or with jupyters solution:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
from nbformat import read
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell 
import sys,os

def find_notebook(fullname, path=None):
    """find a notebook, given its fully qualified name and an optional path

    This turns "foo.bar" into "foo/bar.ipynb"
    and tries turning "Foo_Bar" into "Foo Bar" if Foo_Bar
    does not exist.
    """
    name = fullname.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    if not path:
        path = ['']
    for d in path:
        nb_path = os.path.join(d, name + ".ipynb")
        if os.path.isfile(nb_path):
            return nb_path
        # let import Notebook_Name find "Notebook Name.ipynb"
        nb_path = nb_path.replace("_", " ")
        if os.path.isfile(nb_path):
            return nb_path

class NotebookLoader(object):
    """Module Loader for Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.shell = InteractiveShell.instance()
        self.path = path

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        """import a notebook as a module"""
        path = find_notebook(fullname, self.path)

        print ("importing Jupyter notebook from %s" % path)

        # load the notebook object
        with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            nb = read(f, 4)


        # create the module and add it to sys.modules
        # if name in sys.modules:
        #    return sys.modules[name]
        mod = types.ModuleType(fullname)
        mod.__file__ = path
        mod.__loader__ = self
        mod.__dict__['get_ipython'] = get_ipython
        sys.modules[fullname] = mod

        # extra work to ensure that magics that would affect the user_ns
        # actually affect the notebook module's ns
        save_user_ns = self.shell.user_ns
        self.shell.user_ns = mod.__dict__

        try:
            for cell in nb.cells:
                if cell.cell_type == 'code':
                    # transform the input to executable Python
                    code = self.shell.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell.source)
                    # run the code in themodule
                    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        finally:
            self.shell.user_ns = save_user_ns
        return mod

class NotebookFinder(object):
    """Module finder that locates Jupyter Notebooks"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.loaders = {}

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        nb_path = find_notebook(fullname, path)
        if not nb_path:
            return

        key = path
        if path:
            # lists aren't hashable
            key = os.path.sep.join(path)

        if key not in self.loaders:
            self.loaders[key] = NotebookLoader(path)
        return self.loaders[key]

sys.meta_path.append(NotebookFinder())
import _01_AutoCollect_MQL_DataSet

import _01_AutoCollect_DataSet
```

Thank you and i'm glad for every help i can take :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with nbimporter, I submitted a [PR with a fix here](https://github.com/grst/nbimporter/pull/9). You could hot-patch your version, or (as a temporary workaround) downgrade nbformat:

```
pip install nbformat==4.4.0
```